# Proper way of typing argument which can be either sequence or numpy array

Tags: python, typing

I want to implement a method doing some distance calculations in 3D space, depending on a `position` argument consisting of 3 integer values for x, y, and z coordinate, respectively.

Now it would be nice if the method accepted this `position` argument both as

- `Sequence` of `len=3` and as
- `np.array` of `shape=(3,)`.

I was wondering what is considered current best practice for documenting such a flexible argument type. Using python's relatively new typing module, what I came up with is this:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Union, Sequence

def get_distances(self, 
                  position: Union[Sequence[int, int, int], np.ndarray((3,), dtype=int)]):
    ...
    return distances
```

Is that how to do it? Or is it over the top and stuff like this is better documented via docstring or avoided all together?

Comment: Your type hints are not valid.

Comment: My pycharm linter does not complain. Would you mind pointing out the problem you see?

Comment: Did you try to run this code?

Comment: You are right, the linter doesn't complain but the interpreter does. Do you have a constructive suggestion of how to do the type hints instead?

Comment: The ability to include length of sequences is very limited and is allowed for Tuples only AFAIK. So doing `Union[Sequence[int], np.ndarray]` with proper docstring will be enough both for mypy and other programmers to understand the semantics of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your type annotation, you're instantiating a `numpy` array (which will raise an exception if you run it) Additionally, [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) only takes one argument, the type it contains.

The `Sequence` error will raise:

```
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Sequence; actual 3, expected 1
```

while the `np.ndarray((3,)...)` error will raise:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

You need to just put the type identifier, and specify `int` only once:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Union, Sequence

def get_distances(self, 
                  position: Union[Sequence[int], np.ndarray]):
    ...
    return distances
```

The [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) docpage has a lot of helpful info on how to use the annotations.